# Is there any Windows installer maker with decent scripting capabilities?

Tags: windows, scripting, installer

I need to do complex dependency processing during the installation of our solution, install a few related programs from their own installers and also probably run a few simple tests to determine performance of the machine to choose the right parameters for our application.

I'm thinking something like [Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29) would be a great fit for this task, yet all scripting in installers I found so far is something like [Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29) script of [Inno Setup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inno_Setup) which leaves a lot to be desired and [NSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System) scripting language is nonexistent.

I guess I'm missing something really obvious here as my task is not unique and has probably been solved before.

Comment: When I saw the title, I was going to suggest InnoSetup.  It's a wonderful installer, and I've never had any problems with its scripting. What problems are you having?

Comment: What solutions have you looked at so far?

Comment: @MasonWheeler the problem is my Pascal skills are rusty as I haven't been using it for about ten years. Honestly I'd like to see a real scripting language in the installer but probably I'm asking for too much.

Comment: @jimwise InnoSetup and NSIS

Comment: Installing other programs should be just launching their installers with the correct arguments, or even less if you can convince MIS to do the heavy lifting (via WiX perhaps?). Choosing the right parameters probably shouldn't be exclusive to installation, so you might want to put that into an included tool, which you can then invoke as external program during installation.

Comment: It's relatively easy to use WMI library from within Inno Setup.  E.g., see RRUZ's example of checking for running processing within Inno Setup [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9950718/18192).  This should be sufficient to get basic performance-related data (RAM, CPU speed, etc.)

Comment: i guess you should be able to execute PowerShell scripts from the installer.

Comment: @Asdfg It would be nice but what If powershell is not installed on the destination computer? Should I bring powershell with my installer too?

Comment: you cannot bring PowerShell with your installer as it is a windows feature. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell. Check versions tab.

Answer (score 2):

(Re)Learn pascal and use InnoSetup. You can have innosetup to execute other programs written in your favorite language (after innosetup has installed it) and get the results.

I personally work in PHP on windows. Innosetup drops a basic installation of the PHP interpreter and I call PHP programs.

Comment: It seems you are right and this is the only way. btw won't anti-virus software kill those scripts deployed by Innosetup fearing it could be a virus? I don't want to make my users to turn their anti-viruses off. Now I actually see why there is no decent scripting in installers: anti-viruses killed it.

Comment: On a second thought could you show and example of how do you drop basic php installation and call php programs from Innosetup.